# Calculating the definite integral of $1\over x$ over the range $(0,1]$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

I am learning probabilities and I am not a mathematician.  To calculate a marginal PDF I must integrate $1\over x$ (a conditional uniform PDF) over the range $(0,1]$. The integral of $1\over x$ is $\ln x$ and $\ln x$ at $0$ takes an infinite value.  So I am stuck.

Your advice will be appreciated.

---

Note:  Indeed, I ended up calculating the wrong interval.  The original problem was that a random variable X is uniformly distributed over [0, y] and Y is uniformly distributed over [0, 1].  So what is the marginal of X?

Using the total probability theorem I integrated the marginal of Y (1) multiplied by the conditional of X given Y (1/y).  However I set as limits for the definite integral the range [0, 1] when in reality it is [x , 1] since Y can not be less than X for any given X.

Comment: Can you post the whole problem? Something must have gone wrong earlier if you ended up needing to evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}$.

Comment: " The original problem was that a random variable X is uniformly distributed over [0, y] and Y is uniformly distributed over [0, 1]. So what is the marginal of X?" $$f_X(x)=-\ln(x)\,\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}(x)$$ (Seeing the mess you made of the question, it might be preferable to cancel the modifications here and to repost the problem you are really interested in as a new queston.)

Answer (score 2):

The integral doesn't converge because $$\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \log(\epsilon) = - \infty$$

Comment: @quasi "Actually, the integral does converge" Sorry but what are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, I was integrating ln(x).

Comment: @Jack -- ignore my comment -- I accidentally integrated $\ln(x)$ instead of 1/x.

Comment: @quasi $x \log(x) - x$ ?

Comment: @Jack -- Yes, and using _that_ integrand, the integral does converge. Of course, I was looking at the wrong integrand.

Comment: Carmichaels comment is correct, a probability distribution must be integrable. Quasis answer is relevant but a bit misleading. An improper integral is something like $\int_a^b (1/x)dx$ with $a<0<b$. It is often justifiable then to write the integral as $\int_a^{-\epsilon}(1/x)dx+\int_{\epsilon}^b(1/x)dx$ and then take the limit